# Why AddEdgeStep doesn't work after DropStep of edges in the same traversal using Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have this code which essentially updates properties, removes all old `IsOfType` edges and adds new `IsOfType` edges (if I remove all the method/class abstraction and make it inline):

```
traversal = g.V("Entity:633471488:519").as("entity");

//update properties
traversal.property("text", "new text");
traversal.property("description", "new description");

//drop typeEdges
traversal.select("entity").outE("IsOfType").drop();
//even that causes the same issue(!): traversal.select("entity").outE("HasInner").drop();
System.out.println("traversal after type edges deletion: " +traversal);

//make new typeEdges
traversal.V("Entity:996942848:518").as("type-0").addE("IsOfType").from("entity").to("type-0");

System.out.println("traversal after type edges addition: " +traversal);

//storage  
traversal.select("entity").forEachRemaining({})
```

---

Everything works (even the drop of existing `IsOfType` edges). But the creation of the new `IsOfType` edges doesn't seem to be resulting in new edges on the graph. If I comment out the drop, then creation works fine (!) It is as if the `DropStep` which is before the `addEdgeStep` is happening at the end. I even tried to drop other type of edge and it is causing the same issue (!). It might be that implicit transaction handling is deciding to commit when a `drop()` happens as it is with `next()`, `iterate()` and `forEachRemaining()` ?? If that is the case then drops and creations can't happen within the same transaction using Fluent API which renders it not very useful for real applications :(

Here is the state of the traversals after the deletion and after the additon of two `IsOfType` edges in my run (I tried both Java and Datastax Studio Console):

```
traversal after type edges deletion: 
[
   GraphStep(vertex,[Entity:633471488:519])@[entity], 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[Entity], key=[atClass]}), 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[FilmWithSuperCategories aaa], key=[text]}), 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[dffsdfsd f2313], key=[description]}),   
   SelectOneStep(entity)@[entity], 
   VertexStep(OUT,[IsOfType],edge), 
   DropStep
]

traversal after type edges addition: 
[
   GraphStep(vertex,[Entity:633471488:519])@[entity], 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[Entity], key=[atClass]}), 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[FilmWithSuperCategories aaa], key=[text]}), 
   AddPropertyStep({value=[dffsdfsd f2313], key=[description]}), 
   SelectOneStep(entity)@[entity], 
   VertexStep(OUT,[IsOfType],edge), 
   DropStep, 
   GraphStep(vertex,[Entity:996942848:518])@[type-0], 
   AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(entity)]], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(type-0)]], label=[IsOfType]}), 
   GraphStep(vertex,[Entity:1489781376:516])@[type-1], 
   AddEdgeStep({~from=[[SelectOneStep(entity)]], ~to=[[SelectOneStep(type-1)]], label=[IsOfType]})
]
```

**Edit**

From what I read here (http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#drop-step)

> The drop()-step (filter/sideEffect) is used to remove element and properties from the graph (i.e. remove). It is a filter step because the traversal yields no outgoing objects.

There are no objects being returned so it is not possible to do anything after a drop happens! so I am curious how I can do multiple drops/additions in a single transaction using DSE Graph Fluent API

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your `drop` in a `sideEffect` step, e.g.:

```
g.V(entity1).as("a").sideEffect(outE().filter(inV().is(entity2)).drop()).
  V(entity2).addE("link").from("a")
```

Comment: wow you are awesome! why can't I find any documentation about my use cases :( - I guess it is because gremlin api is just now being standardized

Comment: I am in your debt, sir.  Was driving me mad.